# How to disable the automatic space after typing a word?

Tags: 8.0, nokia-lumia-820

I remember that I have set this before resetting my phone, but now I can't find it anymore.

I don't want there to a be a space automatically inserted after I choose one of the suggested words. I prefer to manually input the space, because if that word is the last one of a sentence, there will be a extra space.

Comment: Are you saying you don't want there to a be a space automatically inserted after you choose one of the suggested words?

Comment: It's smarter than you think. Try selecting a suggested word and then typing some punctuation :-)

Comment: I have never found this! Thanks to @KateGregory

Comment: @Elderry , I have posted an answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out, there is actually a way to do this. I have tested it on my Windows Phone 7 and I am pretty sure that this will work for Windows Phone 8 as well.

Follow these steps:

1. Go to `Settings`
2. Go to `Keyboard`
3. Click on `Typing settings`
4. On the top, you will see something like `Keyboard English tap to change`. Click it
5. Deselect `Insert a space after selecting a suggestion`

Your done :)

Comment: In Windows Phone 8 there isn't an option `typing settings`. You go straight from step 2 to 4.

Answer (score -3):

It is smarter and usual way to have space after the word. There is no way we can change these settings

Comment: Actually your answer is wrong. You can change this behavior in keyboard settings.

Comment: Sorry for unaccept your answer, though I agree that it is a smarter way to have the space now, @karancan is right.